# How to format a vector with mixed float and string elements in order to transfer from python to excel?

Tags: python, excel, com

I use python 3.4 and communicate with Excel using COM.

I want to transfer a vector to Excel using python. When I do the transfer in sequence it works fine. 1,'Test' and 3 appear on the Excel ws.

But the sequence method is slow and in order to speed up I would like to tranfer the vector in one step. Like

```
Range.value = (1,'Test',3) .
```

When I do this I see three 1's on the Excel side. It has something to do with the data type because when I use the formating/data type below it works fine.

---

```
Range.value = ((1,),('Test'),(3,))
```

What I want to do is to transfer a 200+ elements vector with number and strings mixed. How can I create the vector with the working format above using a for loop? Below is my test program.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xlApp=Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.visible=1
# 
xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
Range = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C4")
Range2 = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C7;D9")
vector=(1,'test3',3)

# Elements transfered to Excel one by one
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range('C2').value = vector[0]
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range('C3').value = vector[1]
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range('C4').value = vector[2]
print ('Elements transfered to Excel one by one:', vector) 

# Vector read from Excel
vector2 = Range.value
print('Elements read from Excel using vector: ',vector2)

# Elements transfered to Excel using vector
Range.value = vector
print('Elements transfered to Excel using vector: ',vector)

# Element read from Excel using vector
vector3 = Range.value
print('Elements transfered from Excel using vector: ',vector3)

# Elements transfered to/from Excel using vector with another data type
Range.value = ((1,),('test5',),(3,))
print('Elements transfered to/from Excel using vector with another data     type: ',Range.Value)
```